# What is the best way to automatically self update a website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'd like to find a way update a website from another computer.

What's the best way to approach this?

I'd rather do a push than to have the web server actively scan some shared drive or ip address. Ideally the website itself would accept a multi-form post which would contain a zip file. and if so the program would then replace itself with the contents of the zip file. Is that possible?

Two additional requirements:

1. I'd like to obfuscate this ability as much as possible. Perhaps a separate dll file. - Could the /bin directory have two separate dll files - one that is just standard website and another dll file that could just be dropped into the /bin file. This would accept the upload and rewrite the other files...
2. I'd like some ability to delete this second dll file. Ideally this functionality would be from within the second dll file itself. So browse to website.com/VirtualDirectory/?delete={GUID} and the second dll file deletes itself.

Any thoughts/suggestions towards this end?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a version control system like [Git](http://git-scm.com) to handle your deployments. That way, you automatically get the ability to rollback to a previous version if you need to and you don't have to mess with building and maintaining your own update system.

Comment: Git does not really addresses this question. A system such as CruiseControl, Hudson, DamageControl, or even a svn hook (git probably has similar) all could address this. However I'm specifically looking for a subvert way of doing this.

Comment: How does Git not address the question? You asked for the best way to push updates to your application. You can do precisely that with Git or virtually any other source control system. In fact, that's how many "cloud providers" have you deploy to their servers. Why in the world would you want to over-complicate things by developing your own update system that would likely be less efficient and less secure?

Comment: Git is a source control system. End of story. Tell me what git command pushes compiled code to a remote computer? -None because that is not what it is designed to do.

Comment: The command is `git push`. Git can handle binary files just fine. Yes, it's called a source control system, but it's not limited to text files.

Comment: Okay I'm sold I'll use git. What git command pushes compiled code to a remote computer?

Comment: Compile your code. Check in the binaries for the first time with `git add` and `git commit`. Deploy them with `git push`. When you change your application, recompile it, check in the changes with `git commit`, and deploy them with `git push`. You can set up server hooks to restart your app pool or whatever you need to do after deployment.

Comment: by deploy them with "git push" where do I specify the name of the server & remote directory?

Comment: With Git, you have aliased local and remote repositories rather than directories and servers. Rather than teach the whole workflow in a single comment, I'll just point you to the very thorough [Git documentation](http://git-scm.com/doc). Of course, you're not limited to Git. That was just an example. SVN, Mercurial, or whatever would work just as well. If you're already comfortable with a certain stack, then use it instead.

Comment: Git in no way addresses this issue. I could use the zip/unzip command with the same amount of relevance.
 Meanwhile you've wasted both of our times. I'll delete the question and 
re-phrase it.

Comment: If you will read my previous comment, you'll see that I only used Git as an example. With virtually any version control system, you gain the ability to rollback changes very easily and automatically carry out whatever update routines you need on the server with commit hooks. It's quite a bit more efficient than simply uploading a zip file and a heck of lot less work than writing it all from scratch.